# Arrow keys blocked by vtype mask extjs

Tags: regex, validation, extjs, arrow-keys

I am programming with extjs and am struggling with the interference of vtype mask and the arrow keys.
I am validating some fields using custom vtypes like:

```
Ext.define('ldb.util.IbanVtype', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes',

    // vtype validation function
    vTypeIban: function(value) {
        return this.vTypeIbanRe.test(value);
    },
    // RegExp for the value to be tested against within the validation function
    vTypeIbanRe: /^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2,30}$/,
    // vtype Text property: The error text to display when the validation function returns false
    vTypeIbanText: 'No valid IBAN',
    // vtype Mask property: The keystroke filter mask
    vTypeIbanMask: /[A-Z0-9]/i
});
```

which validates an IBAN field. The field is in a column of a grid an has following editor:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    allowBlank: false,
    vtype: 'vTypeIban',
}
```

The validation works fine, but in all validated fields you can't navigate within the string using the arrow keys.

To enable them i had to add %&' to every mask:

```
vTypeIbanMask: /[A-Z0-9%&']/i
```

Does anybody know how i can enable the arrow keys without allowing unwanted chars in my mask? 
I couldn't figure out why the mask interacts with the arrow keys. Does anybody know something or has a hint for me?

Many thanks in advance,
Greetings
Os

Comment: Please, please also allow whitespace between the IBAN digits. If pasting a whitespace-delimited IBAN, like `DEpp bbbb bbbb kkkk kkkk kk`, it is very annoying when your validation rejects it because of whitespace.

Comment: thx @Corion, i got to check the requirements. Maybe white space had to be forbidden. But do you think it has something to do with the arrow keys?

Comment: Hi @Corion, thx for your hint, i allowed whitespace at the required places. Sadly no progress according to the arrow key problem. Greets Os

Comment: I can't easily replicate your situation, because I don't have a short, self-contained page that loads ExtJs and declares the field appropriately. If you can post a [MCVE], I can look at your problem much easier.